# àngularjs directive countdown

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Im having a countdown that works great. But im looking to add more functionality to it.

in this case, i would like to input a string to use in the countdown ( result would be STRING + countdown).

the string is within the init-mess, but i cant quite get why i cant retrieve it within the directive.

```
<countdown init-val="vm.timersteal " init-mess="Du kan utføre enkel krim igjen om" class="ng-isolate-scope"></countdown>
```

the init-val works, but not the init-mess. How can i be able to get the init-mess within the countdown controller function?

```
angular
    .module('users')
    .directive('countdown', countdown);

function getFormattedTime(secs) {
    var date = new Date(null);
    date.setSeconds(secs);
    return  date.toISOString().substr(11, 8);
}

function countdown() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        template: '<div class=\"{{class}}\" style=\"float:left; margin-right:5px;\"">{{result}}</div>',
        scope: {
            initVal: '=',
            initmess: '='
        },
        controller: function($scope, $interval) {
            console.log($scope.initVal);
            console.log($scope.initmess);
            $scope.countdownVal = $scope.initVal;
            $scope.countdownVal = Math.floor($scope.countdownVal / 1000) - Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000);

          var b = getFormattedTime($scope.countdownVal);
            $scope.class = "";
            if ($scope.countdownVal > 0) {
                $scope.result = b;
            } else {
                $scope.class = "blink";

                $scope.result = "00:00:00";
            }


            $interval(function () {
                if ($scope.countdownVal > 0) {
                    $scope.class = "";
                    $scope.countdownVal = $scope.initVal;
                    $scope.countdownVal = ($scope.initVal / 1000) - Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000);
                    $scope.result = getFormattedTime($scope.countdownVal);
                } else {
                    $scope.class = "blink";

                    $scope.result = "00:00:00";
                }
            }, 1000);
        }
    }



};
```

UPDATE:

now i get:

```
angular.js:13920 Error: [$parse:lexerr] Lexer Error: Unexpected next character  at columns 10-10 [ø] in expression [Du kan utføre enkel krim igjen om].
```

how can this be fixed to allow a string?

Comment: I guess 'm' should be capital case in 'initmess' variable...

Comment: the `initmess` should have `m` in capital. `initMess`

Comment: thanks @Mr.Noddy updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here :

```
scope: {
    initVal: '=',
    initmess: '='
},
```

You declare `initmess` with `=`. So Angular is trying to initialize a double way biding with the value given in `initmess`. And it try to eval an angular expression. But you give `Du kan utføre enkel krim igjen om`.

I believe you want to do that :

```
scope: {
    initVal: '=',
    initmess: '@'
},
```

Documentation on `$compile` and directives : https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile